# Make Text wrap in homepage with 2 positions in it

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm using the Purity III template, and I made 2 'columns' as positions to insert in them some articles in order to show 'em vertically.
But when I crete a loooong message in one (i.e. the left one) it goes over the right column instead of wrapping itself and continue in the lower lines.. What's ging wrong?

Joomla 3.X

Comment: Your text are inside a table with fixed width?

Comment: Mmmm nope why? @Max

Comment: Any link to see this error?